# daypilot-all.min.js SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, daypilot

i trying to use mvc DayPilotScheduler. but error ni js file.

Razor code :

```
@Html.DayPilotScheduler("dps", new DayPilotSchedulerConfig { BackendUrl = Url.Action("Backend", "Home"), Scale = TimeScale.Day })
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Backend() 
{ 
return null; 
}
```

in Layout header:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Scripts/daypilot-all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

version Build 7.8.5684

all file downloaded from  http://mvc.daypilot.org/try/

error picture

```
http://s30.postimg.org/mw1g8pvf5/9_25_2014_1_10_29_PM.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. problem in controller when sending null. Just need data :).

DayPilotScheduler not working with null data.